# NPs - pre-/postmodifiers

Tags: determiners, noun-phrases, adjuncts

Would you consider "both" in the following NPs rather as a predeterminer or a conjunction? If it's a predeterminer, it would determine both NPs, right?

> The swimming pool is both a great place to relax and a perfect spot to do some exercise.

Thanks so much. 
(It's my own sentence)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please post separate questions for each with full details and citing the sources. Try to find an answer to each of the questions and let us know what you have found and why it was not good enough. Good Luck.

Comment: "Both" is a predeterminer in NP structure, e.g. "both the children". But your example is a correlative coordination construction where "both" is paired with "and". Here, "both" is a determinative functioning as a marker of the first coordinate: "The swimming pool is [both _a great place to relax_ and _a perfect spot to do some exercise_]."

Comment: What Bill is saying in his first sentence is that a 'predeterminer' is positioned before a determiner (which he calls, after CGEL, a 'determinative'), not immediately before a noun (group). There is probably a confusion because a 'premodifier' **isn't** a word coming before a modifier and modifying it.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, BillJ wrote:

> "Both" is a predeterminer in NP structure, e.g. "both the children". But your example is a correlative coordination construction where "both" is paired with "and". Here, "both" is a determinative functioning as a marker of the first coordinate: "The swimming pool is [both *a great place to relax* and *a perfect spot to do some exercise*]."